# How to crop image in javafx

Tags: javafx

The idea is to crop the image using a control that allows you to resize the required area from the anchors. for example, profile picture crop.

something like this:
[Clipping Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AdEK.png)

I need, if anyone knows, to help me. thanks.

Comment: Check out [`SnapshotView`](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/SnapshotView.html) from _ControlsFX_, it seems to provide exactly what you want to implement. If you would prefer to implement the functionality yourself then you could always [look at the source code](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx) to see how _ControlsFX_ did it.

Comment: Thanks Slaw, I've seen this control. Thanks for the tip, and I will try to create something different.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`WritableImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/WritableImage.html) to crop a section of an image.

Construct a WriteableImage with its constructor: `WritableImage(PixelReader reader, int x, int y, int width, int height)`

For example:

```
Image original = ....;
PixelReader pixelReader = original.getPixelReader();
Image cropped = new WriteableImage(pixelReader, x, y, width, height);
```